# jQuery.on() does not work in WordPress admin panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm writing my own WordPress(4.1.4) plugin which uses some JavaScript code in admin panel.

The first issue is `$` object is undefined, so I use `jQuery` instead.

Now, I want to handle click on the `button` using jQuery:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".my-button").on("click", function(){
        alert("OK");
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, this simple code does not work, but if I try to use this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".my-button").click(function(){
        alert("OK");
    });
});
```

it works fine.

At first, I thought that jQuery version is too old, but when I checked it, I got `1.11.1`.

So I don't understand why the `jQuery.on()` does not work in my case.

Comment: There might be multiple jQuery plugins being referenced

Comment: Did you contain this code in `jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... })`, to make sure it gets executed when `.my-button` is already available for binding to your event?

Comment: Yes, I did)) But I used `jQuery(function(){});` instead.

Comment: I'm guessing you have an old version of jQuery... what does this alert:
`alert( "You are running jQuery version: " + jQuery.fn.jquery );`

Comment: As I pointed above, I have jQuery v. 1.11.1, I checked it using the `jQuery.fn.jquery` method

Comment: Makes no sense.  All other things being equal, `.on('click')` is functionally the same as `.click()`.  If it was an issue of `.on()` not being supported by your version of jQuery, then you'd get something like an `undefined` error in the console.

Comment: So what exactly are you seeing in the console when the code fails to fire?

Comment: I see nothing in the console. But colecmc's answer helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you code is running at the end of the document by running `<?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>`, then setting the `$in_footer` argument to true. Then the `on` function should work as expected. I've tested in WP version 4.2.1, but it should still work in your 4.1.4 environment. This code will also allow you to use the `$`.

```
(function($){
    $(".my-button").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("OK");
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Details for wp_enque_script:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Thank you so much, colecmc! The `wp_enqueue_script` method helped me!)

Comment: Yes, absolutely use the technique described in this answer.  However, it still does not make any sense.  Simply replacing `.click()` with `.on('click')` should make absolutely no difference... unless you're using a jQuery version that's too old.  And in that case, you should see a console error.

Comment: I agree with you, Sparky. But it's just interesting why `.on("click"...)` does not work and `.click()` works expectedly.