# Where to find a complete list of Javascript (JQuery) events that fire on the WooCommerce admin page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, woocommerce

Where to find a complete list of Javascript (JQuery) events that fire on the WooCommerce admin page?

For example, if you wanted to run a Javascript function **after adding a new attribute to a product** from the product edit page, which event should you use?

The answer to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342148/woocommerce-documentation-list-of-js-events) only reports events in the WooCommerce frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Javascript events for WooCommerce admin can be found in the directory:
> `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/admin`

If you want to use JQuery in the Wordpress admin remember to load your script **after JQuery is loaded**.

Look at these answers:

- [How can I include JavaScript that use jQuery on admin side](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53021/how-can-i-include-javascript-that-use-jquery-on-admin-side)
- [get_template_directory_uri pointing to parent theme not child theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/230085/get-template-directory-uri-pointing-to-parent-theme-not-child-theme)

> Make sure you set the `$in_footer` parameter to **true** for the
> [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) function otherwise the events may not be
> triggered in the Wordpress admin pages.

For more details:

- [jQuery.on() does not work in WordPress admin panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991291/jquery-on-does-not-work-in-wordpress-admin-panel)

#### META BOXES ORDER

- `quantity_changed` triggered when the quantity of the order item line changes (and after updating the totals and taxes of the line)
- `order-totals-recalculate-before` triggered before sending Ajax request to recalculate totals *(after clicking "Recalculate")*
- `order-totals-recalculate-success` triggered when the Ajax request was successful *(after clicking "Recalculate")*
- `order-totals-recalculate-complete` triggered when the Ajax request has completed *(after clicking "Recalculate")*
- `items_saved` triggered after clicking on "Save" and sent the Ajax request
- `refund_quantity_changed` triggered when you change the quantity of a product to be refunded

#### META BOXES PRODUCT VARIATON

- `wc-enhanced-select-init` run actions when variations is loaded *(on product edit page)*
- `woocommerce_variations_loaded` triggered after loading variations via Ajax *(on product edit page)*
- `woocommerce_variations_saved` triggered after saving changes to variations via Ajax
- `woocommerce_variations_save_variations_button` triggered after clicking on the "Save changes" button
- `woocommerce_variations_save_variations_on_submit` triggered after clicking on the "Update" button instead of "Save changes"
- `woocommerce_variations_added` triggered after adding a variation
- `woocommerce_variations_removed` triggered after removing a variation
- `woocommerce_variations_input_changed` triggered after changing any input fields of the variation. This event is triggered after adding the **variation-needs-update** class and enabling the "Save changes" button *(removing the **disabled** attribute)*
- `woocommerce_variations_defaults_changed` triggered after changing the select "Default Form Values"

#### META BOXES PRODUCT

- `woocommerce-product-type-change` triggered when the select "Product Type" changes
- `woocommerce_added_attribute` triggered after adding an attribute row via the "Add" button
- `reload` triggered after reloading the variations panel

#### SETTINGS

- `updateMoveButtons` triggered after sorting payment methods or shipping methods

---

#### USAGE

Use the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook to queue a .js file to run on all admin pages.

In my example I used `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` to get the url of the child theme. To get the URI of the root theme you should use `get_template_directory_uri()`.

```
// queue the "admin-scripts.js" script for all admin pages
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_admin_scripts' );
function add_admin_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 
      'custom_admin_script',
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/admin/admin-scripts.js',
      array('jquery'),
      '1.0',
      true
   );
}
```

Then you will need to create an `admin-scripts.js` file and upload it to the directory: `/themes/child-theme/js/admin/admin-scripts.js`.

```
jQuery(function($){
    // triggered when the product type changes
    $('body').on('woocommerce-product-type-change',function(){
        // run code
    });

    // triggered when the quantity of the order item line changes
    $('body').on('quantity_changed',function(){
        // run code
    });

    // ...
});
```